# How to create a vector whose elements add up to 1?

Tags: r

As an example; If I want to create a vector with 4 elements, the vector should be:

```
c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)
```

The difference of the elements is constant and the sum of the elements is equal to 1. What is the most elegant way to create series (with desired length out, of course) like this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
distance <- 0.05

result <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = distance)

result <- result/sum(result)

result
 [1] 0.000000000 0.004761905 0.009523810 0.014285714 0.019047619 0.023809524
 [7] 0.028571429 0.033333333 0.038095238 0.042857143 0.047619048 0.052380952
[13] 0.057142857 0.061904762 0.066666667 0.071428571 0.076190476 0.080952381
[19] 0.085714286 0.090476190 0.095238095

sum(result)
[1] 1
```

Alternatively, you can define the sequence through the number of elements:

```
n_elements <- 20

result <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = n_elements)
result <- result/sum(result)

result
 [1] 0.000000000 0.005263158 0.010526316 0.015789474 0.021052632 0.026315789
 [7] 0.031578947 0.036842105 0.042105263 0.047368421 0.052631579 0.057894737
[13] 0.063157895 0.068421053 0.073684211 0.078947368 0.084210526 0.089473684
[19] 0.094736842 0.100000000

sum(result)
[1] 1
```

Yet another alternative to make sure we have non-zero elements:

```
result <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = n_elements + 1)

result <- result[-1]/sum(result[-1])

result
 [1] 0.004761905 0.009523810 0.014285714 0.019047619 0.023809524 0.028571429
 [7] 0.033333333 0.038095238 0.042857143 0.047619048 0.052380952 0.057142857
[13] 0.061904762 0.066666667 0.071428571 0.076190476 0.080952381 0.085714286
[19] 0.090476190 0.095238095

sum(result)
[1] 1
```

Comment: I don't want to create a variable like `distance`, I just know `n_elements`. Where did you use `n_elements` by the way ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to mention about that the vector should consist of non-zero elements like at the main question. is there a way to create `c(0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)` with only knowing we have 4 as a parameter ?

Comment: please see my update